# Memory address and array, assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

I have this code on Emu8086:

```
Mov Bx,0000h
Mov Cx,0ah 
Mov Si,0200h
Fillup:
Mov Ax,Array[bx]
Mov Ds:[Si],Ax
Inc Bx
inc si                           
loop FillUp

Array dw 28h,43h,0a4h,4ch,81h,21h,0ceh,0fh,2dh,87h
```

When emulating this happens:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiJWp.png)

The memory table looks like this:

| Address | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0200 | 28 |
| 02001 | 00 |
| 02002 | 43 |
| 02003 | 00 |
| 02004 | a4 |

Enter the digit every two steps, and I don't know why it happens.

I have tried many ways to cycle, but I can't find the solution.

**One last qustion**

How can I  initialize an array of n elements at a specific memory address?

For example, how can I make my entire array of 10 elements that are from the address 0200h? Without moving from the array to the memory address.

Comment: What is it supposed to do?  Note that your `Array` is an array of words (because of `dw`) and so `Array` itself contains the bytes `28h, 00h, 43h, 00h, a4h, 00h`, etc.  Is that what you wanted?  Keep in mind x86 is little-endian and so `dw 28h` is the two bytes `28h,00h` in that order.

Comment: It's true, obviously, more simpler impossible Many many many thanks :D

Comment: One last question 
how to initialize an array of n elements at a specific memory address
For example, how can I make my entire array of 10 elements that are from the address 0200h. Without moving from the array to the memory address. I hope I could have explained myself, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source is an array of *words*. Change 'dw' to 'db'.

Comment: Hours of watching the code screen blinded me, I need a break .

Comment: @Ckris: Just changing `dw` to `db` would mean you're still doing word loads, and still only incrementing your pointer by 1, so the words will overlap.  That might or might not be ok if you correctly handle the end of the array to avoid an over-read / over-write past the end of where you meant to copy to.

Comment: One last question how to initialize an array of n elements at a specific memory address For example, how can I make my entire array of 10 elements that are from the address 0200h. Without moving from the array to the memory address. I hope I could have explained myself, thanks

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve, how you used or what assembler you are using, instruction ORG 200h or ABSOULTE 200h may help work for you, or not.

Comment: And as others suggested, if you are moving on byte at a time, you should change `mov ax, array[bx]` to `mov al,byte ptr array[bx]` and `mov ds:[si],ax` to `mov byte ptr ds:[si],al`. You could also familiarize yourself with `rep movsb` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Like most modern processors, it is byte addressable.  This means that each byte gets its own address, and when we group bytes to make larger word sizes, then that word in memory occupies multiple byte addresses.

We need to consistently tell the processor the same data sizes for the same data types.  The processor doesn't know about data declarations and remember their types the way high level languages do: it sees only instructions, and every instruction that manipulates data — in some sense — must tell the processor how many bytes the data occupies.

Here's a list of things that need to be consistent:

- Pointer size increments — add 2 to pointer to access next word-sized data
- Index scaling — scale an index by 2 for word-sized data
- Data declaration — use `dw` for word-sized data
- Load & store size — use word-sized loads & stores

  - by using word sized source or target register (e.g. `ax`, `bx`, vs. `al`, `bl`)
  - by using "`word ptr`" or "`word`" as per your assembly language